# Calling subclasses overriden abstract methods inside parent's main method

Tags: java, methods, call, subclass, abstract

I have abstract class Tester, with abstract method test() and main method:

```
    abstract class Tester {

     abstract String test();

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          doSomething();

          Tester t = new Tester() {
          @Override
              String test() {
                return "";
              }
          };        
          result = t.test();

          doSomethingElse();
     }            
    }
```

Obviously t.test() will always return "" for this class and any other subclasses.

But I want to call method test() inside of main method, that way that any subclass will have its **own** test method called at its execution (in its inherited main method).

Is that even possible in way I imagined ? Can I somehow declare object t as a subclass object (without knowing his name) so he can use his own implementation of this abstract method ?

Comment: similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988334/inheriting-the-main-method

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you haven't thought through exactly how you wish to design your application / object structure. Try seeing if there is a better way you can organise your objects.

The only way you could make your situation work is if you had a test() method that delegated to the current instance's test0() method or similar. That's a trick Java uses internally in some places.